# Have to specify the parametric type

Tags: scala

I have a Stream trait, that contains following method:

```
sealed trait Stream[+A] {

  def takeWhile2(f: A => Boolean): Stream[A] =
    this.foldRight(Stream.empty[A])((x, y) => {
      if (f(x)) Stream.cons(x, y) else Stream.empty
    })

  @annotation.tailrec
  final def exists(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = this match {
    case Cons(h, t) => p(h()) || t().exists(p)
    case _ => false
  }
}

case object Empty extends Stream[Nothing]

case class Cons[+A](h: () => A, t: () => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]


object Stream {

  def cons[A](hd: => A, t1: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
    lazy val head = hd
    lazy val tail = t1

    Cons(() => head, () => tail)
  }

  def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))

}
```

Take a look at `takeWhile2` body, it calls `foldRight` function.

When I would pass `Stream.empty` instead of `Stream.empty[A]`, I would get compiler error, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `foldRight` infers its type parameter from its first parameter list (ie its zero element).

Since this first element is `Stream.empty`, the type inferred is `Stream[Nothing]`, and so it expects the second parameter to be a `(A, Stream[Nothing]) => Stream[Nothing]`, which is clearly not the case.

The same issue is true with any `fold` operator on collections, `Option`, ...

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have casted `(x,y)` as `Stream.empty[A]` when `f(x)` is true but when `f(x)` is false it will return `Stream.empty[Nothing]` i.e. if you don't specify a `dataType` default of `Nothing` is used. So the `Stream[A]` (expected return type) doesn't match with returned value of `Stream[Nothing]`

Comment: Actually, `Stream` is covariant in `A`, so `Stream[Nothing] <: Stream[A]`.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet, Wouldn't it be correct if the `takeWhile2` returns `Stream.empty[A]` in else statement?

Comment: No. The problem is that when the type inferrer gets to the second parameter list, it has already decided that the type parameter for `foldLeft` will be `Nothing`.